# Existence solution ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the ODE 
$$x'(t)+\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_i x(t)^i=0$$
with condition $x(T)=c\in[0,\infty)$, coefficients $\alpha_i\in[0,\infty)$ and index set $I\subset\mathbb{N}$ finite.
Claim: This ODE possesses a solution on $[0,T]$ if the following condition holds:
$$T<\int_c^\infty\left(\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_i x^i\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}x.$$
Can someone give me a hint how to prove this claim?

Comment: Are you sure you want $x(T) = c$ and not $x(0) = c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use @Robert Lewis hint and assume $x(0) = c > 0$. (The case c=0 is trivial). In order to solve your ODE we have to review the proof of the [Separation of Constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)-Method: We define 
\begin{align*}
f(x) = -\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix^i
\end{align*}
which is strictly negative in $[c,\infty)$. Now we obtain the well-defined and strictly monotone function
\begin{align*}
\Phi\colon [0,\infty) &\to \mathbb{R}\\
x&\mapsto \int_c^x \frac{1}{f(s)}ds
\end{align*}
and with the assumption to $T$ we can conclude $[0,T] \subset \Phi([c,\infty))$. The solution to the ODE is given by
\begin{align*}
x(t) = \Phi^{-1}(t)
\end{align*}
for $t\in[0,T]$. This is easy to show with chain rule.